# Python3 counterpart to Fortran's where

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

The following accomplishes what I want:

```
pylab.scatter(x[z>-99.0], y[z>-99.0], c=z[z>-99.0])
```

But, for the sake of "Don't Repeat Yourself", I would like something similar to what is shown below.  Is this possible in python?

```
where z>-99.0:
  pylab.scatter(x, y, c=z)
```

Comment: `my_var = z>-99.0` then use `my_var`, of course, you should give it a better name than `my_var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, this should do what you want:

```
i = z > -99.0
pylab.scatter(x[i], y[i], c=z[i])
```

You could also try this instead:

```
def where(index, *args):
    return tuple(item[index] for item in args)

x, y, z = where(z > -99.0, x, y, z)
pylab.scatter(x, y, c=z)
```

Comment: Thanks Noctis and Juanpa.  These solutions are indeed in the right direction.  However, I was hoping that I could replicate Fortran's where more closely, thus avoiding the need to index x, y, and z explicitly.

However, I suspect that may not be possible in python, in which case I will go with your solution.

Comment: @MichaelEhrlichman If you don't mind introducing a simple function, you still might be able to get something closer to Fortran. See the edit up above for an additional approach you could take.

Comment: These answers do not replicate Fortran's where exactly, but the are useful and address my "Don't Repeat Yourself" goal.  It seems Python does not have a direct counterpart to Fortran's where.  I am going find a forum to bring Fortran's where construct to the attention of the Python developers.